# How to use axios in Vue2 project created with vue-cli3

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I created a new vue project using the command `vue create axe` using `vue-cli-3.0.016beta`. Then installed axios using `npm install axios --save`. In the `main.js` file I imported `axios` as shown below.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(axios)

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

There is not a bit of code change other than this. Still I get an error like the following:

```
Unhandled promise rejection 
TypeError
​
columnNumber: 7
​
fileName: "http://localhost:8080/app.js line 1065 > eval"
​
lineNumber: 57
​
message: "parsed is undefined"
​
stack: "isURLSameOrigin@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js:57:7\ndispatchXhrRequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:109:50\nPromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:177:7\nxhrAdapter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:12:10\ndispatchRequest@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:59:10\nrun@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:75:22\nnotify/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:92:30\nflush@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9\n"
​
__proto__: Object { stack: "", … }
```

I want to axios globally to use interceptors, hence calling it here in main.js. But if I use it in a view-page there is no error!

is this a bug or I'm doing it wrong? Kindly help me to fix this and use axios globally.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650107/use-axios-globally-in-all-my-components-vue. But I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the error I see is here

`Vue.use(axios)`

`Vue.use` expects a vue installable plugin.

You could have a look at vue-axios

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

but I would highly discourage it.

It's best to create your own `ApiHandler.js` file that handles all the remote stuff separately, and you can easily call from anywhere including vue components and vuex.

here is the beginning of my class

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

class ApiHandler{
  constructor(apiUrl) {
    this.axios = axios;
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl || '';  // this line allow passing a custom endpoint for testing
    this.config = {
      headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },  // can setup to prevent all caching
      baseURL: this.apiUrl,
    };
  }

  /**
   * @param {Object} payload
   * @param {String} payload.username
   * @param {String} payload.password
   */
  login({ username, password }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.axios.post('/api/login', { username: username.toLowerCase(), password }, this.config)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.code === 200 && response.body && response.body.token) {
            resolve(response.body.token);
          } else {
            reject('Bad Login');
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject('internal error');
        });
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

you can then call this from anywhere by...

```
<script>
  import ApiHandler from '../lib/ApiHandler';
  const apiRequest = new ApiRequest();

  // and then anywhere in the script
  let payload = {
    username:'someuser',
    password:'somepassword',
  };
  apiRequest.login(payload)
    .then(()=>{
      // yay - I'm logged in
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // oh oh, display error
    })
</script>
```

this gives you much more flexibility and allows you to separate the remote actions and allows doing first-leg response handling separate of your component, which allows more re-usability.

Comment: I understand Danial. Thanks for answering.  But if the project is some what big, I'm afraid the ApiHandler file might be too big to handle?

Comment: Yes, but you can break the file up into multiple files.where `ApiHandler` would have the main axios reference and import other files, in some ways similar to how the vuex store can be composed.

Comment: Ok! That'll do... Thanks Daniel... I'll select you answer, just wait a couple of days to see if anyone can chip in more. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Vue.use(axios);
```

you should

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
```

then you can use it globally

```
login() {
    this.$axios.post('<host>/api/login', data)
        .then((res) => { // dosomething })
        .catch((err) => { // dosomething });    
}
```

if you want to add  globally interceptors with axios, you can

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// and
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
```