# VueJS 2: How to load static JS in order?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have HTML theme that use jQuery and minified custom JS plugin. Application needs to need load jQuery first than minified custom JS plugin. And also I cannot edit the minified custom JS plugin.

```
mounted() {
  let jqueryJS = document.createElement('script');
  jqueryJS.type = 'text/javascript';
  jqueryJS.src = '/static/js/jquery.js';
  jqueryJS.async = false;
  document.body.appendChild(jqueryJS);

  let pluginsJS = document.createElement('script');
  pluginsJS.type = 'text/javascript';
  pluginsJS.src = '/static/js/plugins.js';
  pluginsJS.async = false;
  document.body.appendChild(pluginsJS);
}
```

If I run app, jQuery does not necessarily load ahead of the minified custom JS plugin.
How to load jQuery first and then load minified custom JS plugin?

Comment: Please share how you are loading jquery now. If you include it before Vue with a normal script tag, for example, it should definitely load before.

Comment: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` in the top of `plugins.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [vue-script2](https://github.com/taoeffect/vue-script2)

```
import VueScript2 from 'vue-script2'
...
mounted() {
  VueScript2.load('/static/js/jquery.js').then(function () {
    VueScript2.load('/static/js/plugins.js')
  })
}
```

Comment: I already import VueScript2 like `Vue.use(VS2)`. When I use it gives error `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: VueScript2 is not defined"`

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar You need to import it before using. I have edited answer, You could replace VueScript2 with  VS2, it doesnt matter, the point is that Vue.use is for script2 tags, while to use it pragmatically you will need to import it each time

Comment: Can I import it once for a whole of apps? I import it at `main.js` but the `VueScript2` cannot be accessed at `App.vue`.

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar you could do something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48652504/239354

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar how exactly you use ? Bear in mind that this will be changed in then

Comment: In `main.js` `import VueScript2 from 'vue-script2'` `Vue.use(VueScript2);` `Vue.prototype.$VueScript2 = VueScript2;` In Vue Component `this.$VueScript2.load(..)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176640/discussion-between-aldarund-and-yosua-lijanto-binar).