# VueJS Router View reactive prop not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm making Router-View based application and Im trying to create table filled with data from reactive property. So far I'm receiving an error that its not defined:

"Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property".

Here is the script:

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            messages : [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getMessages()
    },
    methods: {
        getMessages() {
            let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/messages'
            axios.get(uri).then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data.data
            })
        },
    }
}
```

And here is the template:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="message in messages">
            <td>{{ message.title }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've read the VueJS documentation, looked at some other projects and I'm sure it's right. I have parent App.js where I define the Router-View page.

Comment: What do you get if you do a `console.log(response.data.data)` in the line above `this.messages = response.data.data`?

Comment: Have you tried with lie.. `<tbody v-if="messages">` or `<tbody v-if="messages.length > 0">` .. ?

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović I'm sure that the length is 1

Comment: Well, that is `> 0`, right? Do you use Vue devtools extension?

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović yes `length > 0 is True`. I'm using Vue Dev Extensions and it doesn't appear to have any properties in the Messages Component. I'm using Sidebar Component and it's the only component with properties. Also, console log in the Messages Component is not working, but it does in the main Component

Comment: Maybe you up for a chat, I would like to look at it in person? :)

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović Yes I am can you give me your Discord?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193562/discussion-between-benjamin-beganovic-and-ghostbg).

Comment: I've created a fiddle based on what you built and used a placeholder api for testing purposes:
https://jsfiddle.net/71kvduL9/2/
Check your api implementation and catch errors. Hope the fiddle helps

Answer (score 1):

**At first glance, two things stand out:**

1. `this.axios` looks wrong to me (w/o knowing how your complete component looks).. You can either import `axios` in each `.vue` file that needs to use it, or you can import it globally..
2. You appear to be missing the closing `)` on your `axios` call..

---

***Possible solutions:***

1. [Import Axios globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650107/use-axios-globally-in-all-my-components-vue)
2. Your component should look something like this:

   ```
   import axios from  'axios'

   export default {
       data() {
           return {
               messages: []
           }
       },
       mounted() {
           this.getMessages()
       },
       methods: {
           // could also give this a shot...although I doubt this is the issue
           // var self = this;
           getMessages() {
               let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/messages';
               axios.get(uri).then(response => {
                   // is anything shown here?
                   console.log(response);
                   return response.data.data;
                   // or..
                   // return response.data;
               }).catch(err => {
                   alert(err);
               }).then(data => {
                   this.messages = data;
                   // or...
                   // self.messages = data;
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. You could also try adding a `key` to your items within the loop..

   ```
   <tr v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
       <td>{{ message.title }}</td>
   </tr>
   ```

Comment: I was on my phone when I've posted this that's why it looks unfinshed. I've updated the thread now. Please check, I've applied your solution and didn't work. Also, I don't get anything in the console when I try `console.log(response.data.data)`

Comment: What if you do `console.log(response.data)`? The reason it's not working is because there is nothing to show in `response.data.data`. Is the API working correctly?  If you query it directly/manually, are you able to retrieve data?

Comment: yeah the API is working, console.log is not executing it's not even showing empty array or new line or whatever

Comment: @GhoSTBG if your log output is empty, try to catch any possible errors:
`.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })`

Comment: @GhoSTBG I have also updated my answer with a couple other things you could try..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to close the  tag at the end of the document.