# trying to create a prototype to access my Api (Axios) globally in [vue.js 3] and I always get this error: "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

**the main files**

**the axios file**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOJQ......";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});
```

**the main.js file**

```js
import api from "@/data/db";

const app = createApp({});
app.config.globalProperties.$http = api;
```

**the home file**

```js
async mounted() {
    const response = await this.$http.get("/movie/550");
    console.log(response);
},
```

Comment: What is the `api` you import? (`import api from "@/data/db";`) Is it a wrapper around axios?

Comment: yes it is "wrapper around axios"

Comment: Can you share the code of this file? Is really the axios instance returned?

Comment: i mentioned it at the first : `import axios from "axios";

const token =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5YWI0NWI0ZjRkNTc3Y2Q4N2EzZjM2YzhmNmVk......";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use axios globally in all my components vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650107/use-axios-globally-in-all-my-components-vue)

Comment: @JamesBurgess unfortunately no, my problem in why this issue appearing and how can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hypatia-1uov0?file=/src/App.vue). It logs a promise in the console, doesn't give the undefined error. Try putting your actual key in the db.js file and check if you can make a request to the API.

I think the problem in your code is with this line `const app = createApp({});`

You need to pass a component with the mounted() hook in it as an object param to the `createApp` function. Then you need to `mount` the app.

```js
import api from "@/data/db";
import Home from "@/Home.vue";
const app = createApp(Home);
app.config.globalProperties.$http = api;
app.mount("#app"); // Provide a valid html id that exists in your index.html file
```

Comment: I tried this but I got the same error in the Home Page component specifically in the mounted.

Comment: which is that: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Comment: Did you check out the sandbox I made? I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Could you fork the sandbox and make changes to it to give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?